# Default Title bar appearing even with WindowChrome set

Tags: wpf, windows-10, window-chrome

I'm using WindowChrome, and customising the border and the title bar of my application, and it works fine for the most part:

[image]

However, for some reason when I run on a certain Virtual Machine (in this case, a German language one using VMware), a white border and title bar (though with no title) appears, and covers my custom title bar:

[image]

The odd thing is that I have tried inspecting the application using *Snoop*, and even on the VM, Snoop does not seem to acknowledge this bar exists. e.g. hovering over the different WPF components, and if I use Snoop's "magnify" function, the title bar appears correctly!

[image]

Where could this title bar be coming from and how to get rid of it?

Here is XAML code for a simple application that exhibits the same problem:

```
<Window x:Class="XamlMessing.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:XamlMessing"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="298" Width="399" Background="#FF590B0B">

<Window.Resources>

    <WindowChrome x:Key="MyWindowChrome">
        <WindowChrome.CaptionHeight>48</WindowChrome.CaptionHeight>
    </WindowChrome>

    <Style x:Key="MyWindowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Window}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Window}}">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="ResizeMode" Value="NoResize" />
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="TextOptions.TextFormattingMode" Value="Display" />
        <Setter Property="WindowState" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="WindowStyle" Value="SingleBorderWindow" />
        <Setter Property="WindowChrome.WindowChrome" Value="{StaticResource MyWindowChrome}"/>
    </Style>
    
</Window.Resources>

<Window.Style>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="MyWindowStyle"/>
</Window.Style>

<Grid Margin="0,0,81,107">
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="125,89,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Hello, World" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="61" Width="175" FontSize="24" Foreground="#FFDAE463"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

OK it seems to be fixed by setting...

```
<WindowChrome.GlassFrameThickness>0</WindowChrome.GlassFrameThickness>
```

But I would still be interested to know what was causing it to appear in the first place, since that setting wasn't required on devices other than the VM...